# Meteor Change form values on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I was wondering how can I set values of my forms upon initial page load?
I can change values upon an event, like click event on a certain element (submit button), but how do I do it upon page being loaded.

My html

```
       <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover rsk-tbl vScrollTHead">
 <tr>
 <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_day" type="text" placeholder="Day"/>  </td>
           <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_month" type="text" placeholder="Month"/>  </td>
            <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_year" type="text" placeholder="Year"/>  </td>
        </tr>



      <tr>
       <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_car" type="text" placeholder="Car"/>  </td> 
        <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_dist" type="text" placeholder="Distance"/>  </td>
      </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_a" type="text" placeholder="Location A"/>  </td>
            <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_b" type="text" placeholder="Location B"/>  </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Javascript

```
Template.trip_html.events({
var day = event.target.submit_date_day.value;
var month = event.target.submit_date_month.value;


var year = event.target.submit_date_year.value;

var car = event.target.submit_car.value;
var b = event.target.submit_b.value;
var a = event.target.submit_a.value;
var dist = event.target.submit_dist.value;


if(empty(day) || empty(month) || empty(year) || empty(car) || empty(b) || empty(a) || empty(dist)){
return false;
}

if(!isNumeric(day) || !isNumeric(month) || !isNumeric(year) || !isNumeric(dist)){
    return false;
}

if(day.startsWith("0"))
day = day.replace("0", "");

if(month.startsWith("0"))
month = month.replace("0", "");

if(year.startsWith("0"))
year = year.replace("0", "");

console.log(day, month, year, car, a, b, dist);
Meteor.call('addTrip', day, month, year, car, a, b, dist);

event.target.submit_a.value = event.target.submit_b.value;
event.target.submit_b.value = '';
event.target.submit_dist.value = '';


}});
```

I want the initial page load to have today's day, month and year and once person hits submit button, it stays the same (so people can submit yesterday and even last year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting a default value in the form?

With meteor using blaze, this is what I'd do:

HTML

```
<template name="trip_html">
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover rsk-tbl vScrollTHead">
 <tr>
 <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_day" type="text" placeholder="Day" value={{getDay}} />  </td>
 <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_month" type="text" placeholder="Month" value={{getMonth}} />  </td>
  <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_year" type="text" placeholder="Year" value={{getYear}} />  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</template>
```

JavaScript

```
var today = new Date();

Template.trip_html.helpers({
 getDay() {
  return today.getDate();
 },
 getMonth() {
  return today.getMonth()+1;
 },
 getYear() {
  return today.getFullYear();
 }
});
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp

As far the second part of your question, "once person hits submit button, it stays the same," I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that.  But if you mean that each user has a form, then you could add logic to the helper functions to check to see if this user has already submitted a form and pull the values from a collection rather than setting it to today's date.

I think the keys to what you want to do are 1) use the value attribute in your input elements and 2) use helper functions for your template.

Hope this gives you some ideas!

Comment: Yeah, I did that thing. And it worked flawlessly. Did it a bit earlier, nonetheless thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I added some reactive varibles

HTML

```
<tr>
  <td><input class="form-control input-lg submit_day" name="submit_date_day" type="text" value={{submit_dayvalue}} placeholder="Day"/>  </td>
   <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_month" type="text" value={{submit_monthvalue}} placeholder="Month"/>  </td>
    <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_year" value={{submit_yearvalue}} type="text" placeholder="Year"/>  </td>
</tr>
```

JS (CLIENT)

```
Template.trip_html.helpers({

submit_yearvalue: function(){
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
return currentYear;

},

filter_year: function(){
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
return currentYear;

},

submit_monthvalue: function(){
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth();
return currentMonth+1;

},
```